# GridView, SortedAscendingCellStyle server side databinding

Tags: asp.net

I try to use SortedAscendingCellStyle to assign the style of my gridView this is my ASP Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle CssClass="SortedAscendingCellStyle" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="SortedAscendingHeaderStyle" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle CssClass="SortedDescendingCellStyle" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="SortedDescendingHeaderStyle " />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Nom" HeaderText="Nom" SortExpression="NOM">
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Prenom" HeaderText="Prenom">
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pseudo" HeaderText="Pseudo"></asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Mail" HeaderText="Mail">
                    <ItemStyle Width="140px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

there is no problem when i use DataSourceID, but when I use server side databining the SortedAscendingCellStyle Did Not work, this my code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                EmployeDAL oem = new EmployeDAL();
                this.GridView1.DataSource = oem.GetAll();
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my research it appears that you cannot use these nice attributes you when manually bind your GridView in the code-behind.  You can find another discussion on this topic here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1725183.aspx/1

...and also here...

http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2009/04/19/Manually-Databinding-a-GridView.aspx

Good luck!  I'm trying to figure out a solution to the same problem..